# How to make this form with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build the form below but it's not going as expected lol.

I tried to use ListView/ListTile for the form part but when I put it inside the Column (so I can put the text and the buttons) it desapear. After some googling, i found out that I have to set a fixed heigth with Container or use Expanded, but both solutions ara bad becouse with fixed heigth the form cannot grow as new entries are added and expanded make the buttons go to the end of the screen event with only one entry.

[image: Form I want to create]

The form is something like:
Text('Fulaninho')_______________Text('R$')(TextField)

So... What's the better way to achieve this form?

After giving up of ListView/ListTile, the code I have now is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:navigation/components/border.dart';
import 'package:navigation/domain/subordinatedmerchant.dart';
import 'package:flutter_masked_text/flutter_masked_text.dart';

class PaymentForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentFormState createState() => _PaymentFormState();
}

class _PaymentFormState extends State<PaymentForm> {
  ThemeData _theme;

  var subordinates = <SubordinatedMerchant>[
    SubordinatedMerchant('', 'Paulo Fernandes'),
    SubordinatedMerchant('', 'Felipe Toniloko', tag: 'O cara da panela'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Efetuar Pagamento'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Resumo'),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
            _paymentForm(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _paymentForm() => RoundedBorder(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
              'Fulaninho',
              style: _theme.textTheme.body2,
            )),
            Text(
              'R\$ ',
              style: _theme.textTheme.body2,
            ),
            amountText(),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget amountText() => ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 110, maxWidth: 110),
        child: TextField(
          controller: moneyMask,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          maxLength: 13,
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            counterText: '',
          ),
        ),
      );

  final moneyMask = MoneyMaskedTextController(
    decimalSeparator: ',',
    thousandSeparator: '.',
    precision: 2,
    leftSymbol: '',
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to show what did you do till now in code please

Comment: Does this `Text('Fulaninho')_______________Text('R$')(TextField)` imply that 'Fulaniho' is a TextField and '10,00' is also a TextField.

Comment: Sorry, @SamiKanafani! Added the current code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was put everything inside the ListView... Even the buttons.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Efetuar Pagamento'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15,
          right: 15,
        ),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            AppTitle('Resumo'),
            for (var p in participants) _paymentForm(p),
            _paymentTotal(participants),
            AppTitle('O que você quer fazer?'),
            SecondaryButton('Selecionar Subordinado'),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
            PrimaryButton('Pagar'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The problem is that every time the state changes, it redraws everything. Event the buttons. But solved my problem.